# lost in a sea of rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am so close. I am working to create a simple rspec test for this method. I want it to check that the method receives 'board' and returns a value of c3.

the current test looks like this...

```
  describe 'attempt_win' do
    it 'should contain all possible ai win moves' do
      @player_computer.attempt_win(@board).should include(@ai_winmoves)
    end
    it 'should return a win move' do
      # need to fake grid input here
      board = Board.new
      board.grid[:a1] = "O"
      board.grid[:b2] = "O"

      @player_computer.attempt_win(board).should  include("c3")  #how to say return 'c3' ??
    end
  end
```

the method I'm testing looks like this...

```
  def attempt_win(board)

    @keys_with_o = board.grid.select{ |k, v| v == "O" }.keys  # find Os on the board

    @answers_array = [] # initialize answers array

    @ai_winmoves.each do |k, v| # go through each win move in the ai_winmoves array above.         
      ai_keys = v.select{ |k, v| v == "O"}.keys # grab all computer player's Os from the value hash

      intersection = ai_keys & @keys_with_o 
      # get common elements between two arrays..note: keys_with_o = all current O's on game board
      if intersection.length >=2 # when two intersections exist it means two O's are on the board

        @answers_array << k # add to answers array per iteration

        @answers_array.each do |key|
          # answer = @anskey[@thing.last].to_sym
          puts "which moves can ai win with?"
          puts @anskey[key]
          answer = @anskey[key].to_sym
          puts "attempt win"
          puts answer

          if board.grid[answer] == " " #if win move space is empty take it
            @move = answer               
          else #check for a block move  
            # attempt_block    # handled at line 162               
          end
        end
      end
    end # END @ai_winmoves.each do |k,v|
  end
```

When I run rspec spec, my output related to this test looks like this...

```
    attempt_win
      should contain all possible ai win moves
  which moves can ai win with?
  c3
  attempt win
  c3
      should return a win move (FAILED - 1)
```

So I need to somehow capture the "c3" in my rspec expectation

anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What does your test code look like?

Comment: Ah that, in fact, is my question. I'm not sure what the test SHOULD look like.

Answer (score 0):

ok so the test turned out to be this...

```
  describe 'attempt_win' do
    it 'should contain all possible ai win moves' do
      @player_computer.attempt_win(@board).should include(@ai_winmoves)
    end
    it 'should return a win move' do
      # need to fake grid input here
      myboard = Board.new
      myboard.grid[:a1] = "O"
      myboard.grid[:b2] = "O"

      @player_computer.attempt_win(myboard).should  eq(:c3)
    end
  end
```

The problem was located in how I was returning my answer in the method...Rspec made me write it correctly...

```
  def attempt_win(board)

    @keys_with_o = board.grid.select{ |k, v| v == "O" }.keys  # find Os on the board

    @answers_array = [] # initialize answers array

    @ai_winmoves.each do |k, v| # go through each win move in the ai_winmoves array above.         
      ai_keys = v.select{ |k, v| v == "O"}.keys # grab all computer player's Os from the value hash

      intersection = ai_keys & @keys_with_o 
      # get common elements between two arrays..note: keys_with_o = all current O's on game board
      if intersection.length >=2 # when two intersections exist it means two O's are on the board

        @answers_array << k # add to answers array per iteration

        @answers_array.each do |key|

          # puts "which moves can ai win with?"
          # puts @anskey[key]
          answer = @anskey[key].to_sym
          # puts "attempt win"
          # puts answer

          if board.grid[answer] == " " #if win move space is empty take it
            @move = answer              
          else #check for a block move  
            # attempt_block    # handled at line 162               
          end
        end
      end
    end # END @ai_winmoves.each do |k,v|
    return @move 
  end
```